# Changing to position fixed, bad display

Tags: html, css, menu, menubar

I have a menu bar for my website:it's in the default position, but I want a fixed menu bar!
When I put "position:fixed", it doesn't display correctly(in a browser). Please help me.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 z-index:99;
 cursor: pointer;
  position:fixed;
}
li {
 font-family:odin rounded;
 font-size:40px;
    float: left;
 height:55px;
 background-color:rgb(249,249,249);
 width:20%;
 border-right:1px solid black;
 transition:color 1s, background-color 1s
}
li:hover {
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
}
li a {
 
    display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img.logo {
 height:55px;
 width:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:8px;
 z-index:99;
}
.text  {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
}
a.main:hover {
 background: transparent url('main.html');
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
 <ul class="barre">
  <li class="text"><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/kPPHmo/logo.png" alt="problem"></a><pre style="font-family:odin rounded">    Team NoMaD</pre></li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Menu</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'members.html';">Membres</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'calender.html';">Calendrier</li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Contact</li>
  
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

The menu isn't in one line: with a width 100%;it's not in one line...
And in a browser, it's not beautiful!

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZjYMy (a link for the codepen project!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just add `width:100%;` in `ul` like below

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 z-index:99;
 cursor: pointer;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
li {
 font-family:odin rounded;
 font-size:24px;
    float: left;
 height:55px;
 background-color:rgb(249,249,249);
 width:20%;
 border-right:1px solid black;
 transition:color 1s, background-color 1s
}
li:hover {
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
}
li a {
 
    display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img.logo {
 height:55px;
 width:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:8px;
 z-index:99;
}
.text  {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
}
a.main:hover {
 background: transparent url('main.html');
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <ul class="barre">
  <li class="text"><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/kPPHmo/logo.png" alt="problem"></a><pre style="font-family:odin rounded">    Team NoMaD</pre></li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Menu</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'members.html';">Membres</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'calender.html';">Calendrier</li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Contact</li>
  
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with the logo image and 5 list items at 20% its trying to fit more than 100% in one line.
Try less than 20% on the li items

Comment: ReSedano nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Flex for this: it's very powerfull. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxKZaw.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 z-index:99;
 cursor: pointer;
    position:fixed;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
}
li {
 font-family:odin rounded;
 font-size:40px;
  flex:1;
    /*float: left;*/
 height:55px;
 background-color:rgb(249,249,249);
 /*width:20%;*/
 border-right:1px solid black;
 transition:color 1s, background-color 1s
}
li:hover {
 color:white;
 background-color:black;
}
li a {
 
    display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img.logo {
 height:55px;
 width:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:8px;
 z-index:99;
}
.text  {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;
 justify-content: center;
}
a.main:hover {
 background: transparent url('main.html');
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
 <ul class="barre">
  <li class="text"><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/kPPHmo/logo.png" alt="problem"></a><pre style="font-family:odin rounded">    Team NoMaD</pre></li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'main.html';">Menu</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'members.html';">Membres</li> 
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'calender.html';">Calendrier</li>
  <li class="text" onclick="location.href = 'contact.html';">Contact</li>
  
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```